# Is a low pass RC circuit the same thing as a first order Butterworth filter?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Is a low pass RC circuit the same thing as a first order Buterworth filter?

I was just curious because i googled Buterworth filter and they always show the filter with an inductor in the circuit.

Consider the transfer function for a low pass RC circuit:

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{1+RCs}$$

and the magnitude response for a first order butter worth filter:

$$|H(j \omega)|= H(j\omega)~H(-j\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{\omega}{\omega_c})^2}}$$

The same thing or different animals?

Comment: Relative to @LvW's comments below, have you tried a "1st order Bessel"? Or Chebyshev?

Answer (score 4):

A first order filter has only one free component, so only one degree of freedom, its 3dB bandwidth. You have an arbitrary choice of one component, and then the other is set by the RC time constant needed.

It's only when you get to second order filters (or higher), you get an extra degree of freedom (or more), so now you can define a shape as well as a bandwidth. It's now meaningful to discuss whether it's a Butterworth, Cheby, Bessel or whatever shape.

Whereas a synthesis program for an Nth order filter of any shape can generally set N equal to 1, the resulting filter is trivially identical to the basic first order RC.

When you make the substitution s=jw, and compare like with like, then yes, a first order Butterworth describes the same response as an RC.

It's more useful to say that the Butterworth response *reduces to* a low pass RC response when it's first order, rather than a low pass RC response is a first order Butterworth.

Comment: *"A first order filter has only one free component"* can you please elaborate? I mean, when I make an first order circuit with a resistor and a capacitors I have **2** elements. If I place them on a breadboard, both are free, when I solder them, both aren't free...

Comment: @Huisman A 1st order low pass filter can be completely understood analytically from \$\frac1{1+s}\$. But focusing only on the characteristic equation only one degree of freedom is added by \$\frac1{1+\tau\,s}\$ which allows setting the roll off. That's all you get. In 2nd order, you have a new added term, either \$Q\$ or else \$\zeta\$, which sets and entirely new and separately interesting behavior. This extends beyond 2nd order, though the descriptions becomes more difficult to wrap your mind around, which is why effort is given to breaking down higher order into lower order combinations.

Comment: @jonk I know, I think I wouldn't have used the word "component" but "variable". Component is used for electrical components, esp on a SE.EE site...

Comment: @Huisman Oh. I see. You were quibbling with that word. Still, the idea of a degree of freedom stands. There is only one degree of freedom in the 1st degree characteristic equation.

Comment: +1 for the effort making the answer nonambiguous

Comment: IMHO, the last sentence should be left, only.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Do you mean replace the last, single sentence, paragraph 'It's more useful ... order Butterworth', with the word 'left'? It seems unlikely, but I can't think what else you might mean.

Comment: @Neil_UK Don't forget the added "IMHO". :-) But, yes, all filters reduce to a 1st order form, as LvW mentions in the comments, below; it would be inappropriate to name the 1st order Butterworth, or Chebyshev, or Pascal, since the 1st order is common to all, so a first order is nameless.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a low pass RC circuit the same thing as a first order Butterworth
>   filter?

<s>Yes. First order RC passive filters are always Butterworth filters. The term in the transfer function that controls the damping factor (shape), doesn't exist in first order passive filters.</s>

Edit:

Yes, same shape. First order RC passive filters always have a Butterworth shaped response, although since they cannot have any other shape, they are usually not referred to as Butterworth filters. The term in the transfer function that controls the damping factor (shape), doesn't exist in first order passive filters.

/Edit

First order passive filter schematics are often not shown in filter articles because they are trivial. Second (and higher) order passive filters are often made using inductors, they are more interesting, so articles will discuss them.

Comment: No - I think the answer is not correct. The BUTTERWORTH response is available for a filter order of n=2 or higher. A second-order BUTTERWORTH function has a pole-Q of Qp=1/SQRT(2). A 1st-order lowpass has a Q-value of 0.5 only. For 1st-order filter responses we cannot discriminate between different responses...

Comment: @LvW See the table with n=1 at [this wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter).

Comment: @jonk, at first - I do not blindly trust wiki - and secondly, they have listed Butterworth polynominals ....and, formally, they have included also a first-order expression (just to complete the table). OK - why not? But you certainly will agree that I also could claim that this is a 1st-order Bessel-Thomson or 1st-order Chebyshev expression. Buth this would be crazy (in my eyes). Therefore, it is misleading to call this "Butterworth" response because this implies that there would be other 1st-order  possible responses. But this is not the case.

Comment: @LvW I'm only saying that *all* 1st order filters can be analyzed by that case. The only change possible is the cutoff and that is an irrelevant detail for analytical purposes. Butterworth filters have a definition, "flattest amplitude." I'm just saying that the OP is allowed to call it Butterworth. Also, while I won't debate your assertion, it is still better to just see it that way as it remains consistent in shape as the higher order filters are later introduced. Just my opinion.

Comment: @LvW - good point, edited to make it more clear.

Comment: @jonk I am sorry, but LvW is right, Chebyshev polynomials of N=1 are reduced to the same as a Butterworth of N=1, or a Bessel, Legendre, etc, which makes the 1st order common to all. This means that names canot be assigned to the 1st order case, but, sure, if one wants to call it a particular way, go ahead, but it would not be correct. My feeble attempt at describing this would be the same as zero: it's common to all counting ways, but you go integer, rational, irational, etc, so saying zero is imaginary would mean seeing only what you want to see ("you" as in generic "you").

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I didn't disagree with LvW. (That may not have been as obvious as it should have been.) I'm only saying that if you are showing filter shapes to someone, they will far far more likely put the 1st order filter response into the same box as they put Nth (N>=2) order Butterworth filters, when they will be putting other N>=2 filters into different boxes. It's not a precise mathematical approach. It's a Sesame Street cartoon show of "which of these things is not like the other?" approach.

Comment: @jonk Yes, but that's where the mistakes come from. A 1st order is like 0: it doesn't count anything, but it's there in case you have nothing. Same with filters: 1st order is there as the start of any and all (because 0th order means no filter), and "counting" only starts at the 2nd order. As such 1st order should not be included in any particular filter's description other than to say that that's the start and they are not particular to that filter. Unfortunately it's not done so and people think that a 1st order is a Butterworth because it's included in a table. IMHO it should not be a show.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen People have to take single steps as they move forward. They can't just jump into the deep end. (Well, most of us have to take it slowly. Genius is of course excluded.) I'll leave it there.

Comment: @jonk Agreed, it does seem like a matter of opinions. It's unlikely this discussion would influence the rest of the world about this. :-)